# Changes not appear in develop branch

Tags: git, git-merge

I have a new feature in a feature branch and merged that branch to the develop branch. After that, other devs merged their feature branches also.

The problem is, now my changes don't appear in the develop branch, and nothing happens when I merged my feature branch again.

Comment: Well it's always possible that those other merges removed some/all of your changes.  And since you already merged the branch once, Git will detect this when merging again, which will just no-op.  You should look at those other commits.

Answer (score 0):

I'm just explaining your use cases and why you are not able to see your changes in the branch *Develop*

1. Consider that **Develop** is a parent branch and we cut two new 
   branches like **Feature1** and Feature2 on top of the branch 
   **Develop**.
2. Consider that you added some changes in the branch **Feature1** and
   merged into parent branch Develop. Now all the changes are
   **Feature1** changes are merged into the branch Develop and ***GIT*** is recorded the same.
3. Now Consider that your friend added some changes on top of the
   branch **Feature2** which does not have your changes.

> Q: Why your changes are not available in the **Develop** branch?

A: As per point #3, When the merge **Feature2** to **Develop** happens, your changes may be overridden this merge.

> Q: Why the changes are not reflecting even after Re-Merge?

A: Git already recorded that you merged your feature changes into the branch Develop so you won't see any difference when you compare between Feature1 to Develop branches

Finally, these kinds of cases can appear only when you and your friend modified the same files in the branches **Feature1** and **Feature2**

I hope you understand the case now and cleared some facts around GIT.